# Libraries classes in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm going to develop an application on Ruby on Rails which has many library classes. But I have no such idea. Is it possible or not in Rails? If possible, how can I develop my own library class in rails application? Please suggest me.

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: I want to develop my own libraries class just like nuku framework libraries in Joomla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since i do not understand your question very well, i can only guess what you mean.

there are several ways of abstracting logic in ruby and ruby on rails.

the most general approach is creating ruby gems. this is a package of ruby code that can be used in every ruby project. it's possible to hook into rails through gems via railties.

there are two things that are specific to rails. the first one are plugins, that work very similar to gems and are considered a legacy way of providing functionality, but there are still some plugins around, especially for rails apps prior version 3.

the other thing is engines. these are micro-applications that can be mounted into any rails app. they are self-contained and can provide a lot of functionality based on their namespaced routes.

since rails is based on rack, it's also possible to hook any rack-conform ruby application into the rails router. through this approach it's possible to connect rails apps with ie. sinatra applications.

Comment: Which type of file can I include in lib folder?

Comment: you can put anything in a lib folder. it's just a regular folder.